# How can I keep "require" working for dynamic expressions

Tags: node.js, webpack, webpack-4

I want to bundle a Node.js script, which somewhere calls `require(expression)`. After bundling the script with webpack, require fails. This is a super simplified example:

```
// main.js
const x = require(process.argv[2])
console.log(x)
```

I would like to either have a "normal" require for this case or tell webpack to include a specific file which I know will be required in the future (after bundling). To stick with this example, I know the value of `process.argv[2]` ahead of bundling.

Note: The code doing the expression based require is a dependency, so I cannot tweak require code.

This is my webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './test.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'test.js'
  },
  target: 'node'
}
```

Comment: Adding `target: 'node'` should work for you

Comment: I already have target: 'node' set.

Comment: Interesting... `/* webpackIgnore: true */` could work too. By doing that, require would not be processed by webpack. Try doing: `require(/* webpackIgnore: true */ process.argv[2])`

Comment: i could add `require(/* webpackIgnore: true */  process.argv[2])`, but the actual require happens in a dependency I cannot modify.

Comment: ouch... At least try modifying the code on node_modules and see if that could work, otherwise i recommend you going directly to webpack repo and open a question there. Make sure to state that this is a non-trivial example and nobody at stackoverflow knew it.

Comment: are you sure that `process.argv[2]` has expected value? (isn't malformed, trimmed or something)

Answer (score 1):

The *require* path is relative to the file it is used in. So you'll need to figure out the path from where *require* is executing to the file it's loading from the parameter. Then prepend the relative part to the parameter.

Comment: yeah. i considered this. working with absolute file paths also does not work.